# Cannot open Software & Updates or Additional Drivers and can't add PPAs

Tags: drivers, apt, software-center, ppa, additional-drivers

I have searched for my issue and none of the answers in other peoples' questions helped my case. In my case, I cannot open Software & Updates or Additional Drivers, and I can't add any PPAs through the terminal. Ubuntu Software works just fine.

When attempting to launch `software-properties-gtk` through the terminal, I am greeted by the following error (which is similar to the error I get when trying to add a PPA):

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 154, in __init__
    SoftwareProperties.__init__(self, options=options, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.reload_sourceslist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 613, in reload_sourceslist
    self.distro.get_sources(self.sourceslist)    
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptsources/distro.py", line 91, in get_sources
    raise NoDistroTemplateException(
aptsources.distro.NoDistroTemplateException: Error: could not find a distribution template for Elementary/next
```

I have a sneaking suspicion it has to do with the fact that I switched Ubuntu's default version of Python from Python 2.7 to Python 3.8 for the purposes of running code within Visual Studio Code (which uses the system terminal, rather than its own), but I can't be certain, and I'd like some input on this situation.

**Edit:** I'm running Ubuntu 20.04. I forgot to mention that originally.

Comment: That python switch was a bad idea, also quite unnecessary.

Comment: You haven't given you release details, but you were right I believe, so return your `python` back to whatever is appropriate for your unstated OS/release (or learn to live without the Ubuntu tools that require the default `python`)

Comment: I'm still having a hard time trying to get it back to what it was. I tried setting the default version of python to `Python 2.7.18rc1` and that didn't do it. Previously, when I had it updated, it was reading `Python 3.8.2`, and before that, it was 2.7, but i don't recall what it read specifically.

Comment: In my 20.04 it is Python 3.8.2

Comment: I actually just said "whatever" and reinstalled Ubuntu. Actually kind of glad that I did, because I've been able to free up way more storage even with all the same games installed (I've freed up about 600GB of storage some how). Everything seems to be working, but any time I type `python --version` into the terminal, it returns `Python 2.7.18rc1`. Not sure why, since Ubuntu 20.04 was supposed to drop support for Python 2.